# Cordova facebook connect plugin fail on login in android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

in my android application ( phonegap ) i am using facebook service for login. but when i try to login using facebook it will fire an error  :

Error : `Cordova  facebook connect plugin fail on login! Facebook error:Failed to receive access token`

Code working fine on **emulator**. but when i test in **real device** it will fire me above error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Facebook app is not set to sandbox mode.

[image]

The **Sandbox Mode** should be selected as **Disabled**. As per the documentation, if this is enabled, only developers can access the app. Hence, testing on a real device may through an error.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you have your Facebook App has the platform you are using enabled. If you are using Android, you need to add android, if on iOS, you need to add it. You find that in your App Settings on Facebook